# mocha-phantomjs-core - slimerjs hangs without any error

Tags: slimerjs, mocha-phantomjs

Using [mocha-phantomjs-core](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs-core) with [slimerjs](https://slimerjs.org) 
I manage to run my tests successfully from CMD:

```
slimerjs mocha-phantomjs-core.js tests.html tap
```

Slimerjs window opens, I see the a browser window and all seems good, but the CMD doesn't finish (seems to wait for something). nothing is happening until I close the slimerjs window. I want to output the test result (using TAP reporter) as a file.

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs-core/issues/25

`system.stderr.writeLine` doesn't work on **CMD** or **GIT bash**... I've changed `mocha-phantomjs-core.js` `fail` function stderr to do stdout instead. now I get the **error**:

> Likely due to external resource loading and timing, your tests require
>   calling window.initMochaPhantomJS() before calling any mocha setup
>   functions. See #12

So I had to add `window.initMochaPhantomJS()` before the setup function.. how silly! all this because I couldn't see any error due to the `stderr` issue not printed